# Template Build in VMWare

Tags: templates, vmware, esxi

Hi I am newbie to VMWare. Can someone let me know what is Template Build in VMWare.

I am aware of Basic VM Concepts and How to deploy vm from template. But I am not aware of template Build.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is like a master copy of your machine and its configuration.
if u need to make frequent clones of a VM then a Template is created which is used to make copies

Answer (score 0):

VM Templates is A copy of pre-installed VMs containing all the software and configuration settings that would make the VM work when deployed.